# I can't install a platform in eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

1. When I choose available packages and Click the repository site checkbox to display the components available for installation I get a line check box that says "some packages were found but are not compatible updates" from my sdk manager i have downloaded every package and have updated everything so I do not understand why there are NO Available packages?
2. also when I created an avd to  see the emulator work I get the following message after I click launch

**"invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information"**

It  appears the command line above has a forward slash instead of a back slash. Any thought on how to get this working

Comment: I'm assuming you tried this already right? - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: yes but i also can not select a package

Answer (score 1):

You should install the Android SDK in a folder that doesn't contain spaces...
Spaces make everything go wild...

Comment: please exolane the spaces what do you mean by that

Answer (score 1):

invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk......

This error is reported because you installed the sdk in "Program Files" directory. Please make sure that you install the sdk in a folder without any spaces in the name.